# How to make tunnels in linux without using SSH?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, tunnel

I have two machines on my network with IPs of `192.168.1.2`(Server) and `192.168.1.3`(Client). In the Server, there is an HTTP server running on the `lo` interface on port 8080 (127.0.0.1:8080) which only can be accessed by local users. I want to forward that port to the Client. The only way I found is by through an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 user@192.168.1.2 -N -vv
```

For this process, I needed to have the password or the private key of that user. Is there an alternative way to make such a tunnel without using the SSH utility assuming that I  `don't have any kind of credentials` but do `have access to execute commands` on the server? My final goal is to be able to connect to the HTTP server on the at `192.168.1.2`  from the client as localhost.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to a different server as localhost? Why not just allow outside connections? That would be way easier and well supported. You could even just run a reverse proxy to allow that kind of connection if you can't influence the webserver itself. Depending on configuration that connection would seem like coming from the host itself.

Comment: Actually it's for a CTF event that I am currently working on, I wanted the users to forward a certain port that is available only for localhost to view. I don't want it to be exposed publicly. Actually I found a way around. I can use a tool called chisel for that.

Comment: If you've resolved your issue, I'd suggest you add it as an answer and accept your own answer - sounds weird but perfectly fine :-) That way it will be available for other users who might need it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool called **[chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel/)** that let me do exactly what I wanted to do.

For this you will have to have some kind of a way to execute commands. I was able to upload the executable file to the server and work with it.

```
chisel server --reverse --port 9001   # Client side
```

This will start a reverse proxy and listen on port 9001 for any connections on the client side.

```
chisel client 192.168.1.3:9001 R:8080:127.0.0.1:8080 # Server side
```

By executing this, a connection will be made to the server at the client side and forward the traffic for the specified port(in this case 8080) to the server at the server side.

Answer (score 0):

GNU netcat has this functionality built-in:

```
nc -L localhost:8080 -p 9001
```

It seems like the simplest solution that gets the job done.

Comment: I get an error saying "netcat: invalid option -- 'L'" with this command.

Comment: Check that you have a modern GNU netcat.